# Unbreakable reasoning

Tags: synonyms

Is "**an unbreakable reasoning**" idiomatic in English?

(the meaning being that the reasoning has no flaws and can not be invalidated)

Could you propose synonym adjectives of unbreakable in this context that are idiomatic?

Thank you!

Comment: How can a hypothesis be unbreakable? The purpose of a hypothesis is to discover if it's breakable. If it's unbreakable, then it's a fact, or a theorem or a tautology or similar. Are you rather asking for strongly positive words to describe a hypothesis?

Comment: Recognizing that *unbreakable* doesn't apply to hypotheses, since they aren't proven yet, and that theorems and postulates are assumed things, what about proofs? For that, the term *unassailable*,  *incontestable*, or a synonym, might apply.

Comment: Edited. Just consider the question with "unbreakable reasoning".

Comment: No, it is not idiomatic and sounds like the person speaks another language.

Answer (score 1):

For *reasoning*, the following words might apply:
strong, valid, correct, or  unassailable:

[Wiktionary *unassailable*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unassailable)
Undeniable, incontestable or incontrovertible.
Synonyms: incontestable, unopposable, impregnable, invulnerable
*She won the debate with her unassailable logic.*

Comment: Thank you. So the synonyms from your definition (incontestable, unopposable, impregnable, invulnerable) do not apply to reasoning?

Comment: They do apply. Note the colon after my word *unassailable*, introducing the Wiktionary definition with additional synonyms.

Comment: 'Impeccable' is good also.

Answer (score 0):

One word answer(s): *indisputable*, *incontrovertible*, *self-evident*.

Actual answer:

If an argument adheres to the rules of logic without exception, it's said to be logically complete, inferentially true, or logically valid.

Whether or not the *premises* are true is a separate issue, but if they are, one could say that the argument's *ground-truths* are valid, or that the premises are confirmed (confirmed analytically or confirmed empirically).

The argument has 'unbreakable reasoning'.
would be synonymous with
**The argument has valid ground truths and is logically complete.**

Comment: ground truths? Never heard that....

Answer (score 0):

We often use:
**unassailable** **reasoning**

: not assailable : not liable to doubt, attack, or question
an unassailable argument
an unassailable alibi

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unassailable)